# Selenium wait.until method

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

Hello fellow programmers, I have a simple question.

Is

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
```

equivalent to

```
time.sleep(10)
```

?

I'm developing this selenium app and sometimes the server traffic is quite massive which leads to different loading times when moving from page to page. I found `time.sleep(N)` isn't efficient but if I use the `wait.until` `EC` block will the code execute once the condition is met?
It won't waste time if use `wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 60)` and the page loads in 3 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.sleep(10)` and `wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)` both are **explicit waits.**

The main difference is that

`time.sleep(10)` is the worst kind of explicit wait.

What it means is that it will ***halt*** the program execution for the defined time period, in this case, `10 secs`.

Whereas `WebDriverWait` will look for `EC` conditions every **500ms** if found then return if not retry again and again until a timeout occurs and then throw

```
TimeOutException
```

which is a generic error again.

Also,

> Since explicit waits allow you to wait for a condition to occur, they
> make a good fit for `synchronising` the state between the browser and
> its DOM, and your WebDriver script.

here is the official [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) for explicit waits.

Answer (score 0):

The hardcoded pause of `time.sleep(10)` and the explicit wait of `wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)` are definitely not the same.
The hardcoded pause of `time.sleep(10)` will pause execution of the code for the period of 10 seconds with no conditions.
The explicit wait of `wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)` will poll the web page until the specified condition is met.  Once the condition is met your code will continue execution immediately.
For example if you defined your explicit wait to wait until element located by `div.selected` is visible, Selenium will poll the DOM every some predefined period, lets say every 100 milliseconds and when it founds such element visible the `wait` will finish and your code will continue execution.
In case the condition was not met up to the defined timeout, in the example above it is 10 seconds, Selenium will throw `TimeoutException` Exception.
There are a lot of tutorials about this, for example [here](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver)